# По удивительному совпадению(,) эта сумма в точности равна той

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Из кабинета капитана была украдена небольшая сумма денег. По удивительному совпадению(,) эта сумма в точности равна той, что была собрана с жителей района.

Нужна ли запятая в отмеченном месте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Из кабинета капитана была украдена небольшая сумма денег. **По удивительному совпадению** эта сумма в точности равна той, что была собрана с жителей района.*

Обстоятельственный оборот в начале предложения обычно не обособляется. Он не имеет значение вводности, относится ко всему предложению и выделяется только произносительной паузой.

Для сравнения: ***Что удивительно***,  эта сумма в точности равна той, что была собрана с жителей района. Вводное сочетание обособляется, при чтении выделяется паузой.