# По официальным сообщениям(,) затор составил около 40 км

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> 1. По официальным сообщениям(,) затор составил около 40 км.

Из моего [предыдущего](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/458178/192807) вопроса:

> 2. По удивительному совпадению(,) эта сумма в точности равна той, что была собрана с жителей района.

Нужна ли запятая в первом примере? На аск.фм сказали, что нужна.

Во втором примере предлог тот же, но запятая не нужна. Чем обусловлена разница? Тем, что в первом примере "по" можно заменить "согласно"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно справочнику Лопатина, "*Вводные слова и сочетания слов выделяются или отделяются запятыми*". Далее в справочнике определяется, что такое вводные слова и выделяются их категории, в частности:

"*г) заключают в себе указание на источник сообщения: вижу, говорят, думаю, известно, как говорили, как известно, как полагаю, как помнится, как помню, как слышно, на взгляд, по-вашему, по мнению (кого, чьему), помнится, помню, по-моему, по понятию (чьему), по пословице, по преданию, по рассуждению (чьему), по сведениям (чьим), по словам (чьим), по слухам, по соображениям (чьим), **по сообщениям (чьим)**, по-твоему, по убеждению (чьему), сказывают, слышно, слышу, с точки зрения, судя по всему;*"

В данном случае предложение 1 начинается именно таким вводным сочетанием, заключающим указание на источник сообщения. Таким образом, запятая тут нужна.

Answer (score 3):

Если оборот указывает на источник информации (случай 1), то он является вводным и обособляется.

Вводные сочетания «по сообщению (кого-либо, чего-либо, чьим-либо)», «по сообщениям (кого-либо, чего-либо, чьим-либо)» обособляются.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_594

А совпадение не может являться источником информации.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны два варианта:

(1) ***По официальным сообщениям*** затор составил около 40 км.

(2) ***По официАльным сообщениям,*** затор составил около 40 км.

В первом случае оборот входит в основной состав предложения и не обособляется.

Во втором случае оборот обособляется, так как называет источник информации (это функция  вводного слова).

Варианты различаются интонационно (ударения указаны).

Примечание. Розенталь сочетание ***по сообщению кого-либо*** относит к вводным словам, но оборот ***по официальным сообщениям*** отличается от этого сочетания по структуре.

Comment: Есть ли у Розенталя эта разница? На Грамоте нету. Пока что не могу понять вариант (1).

Comment: Нет, первый вариант недопустим. Во-первых, правила, а во-вторых, смысл нарушается. Получается "затор по сообщениям". Ср. "По второму цеху брак составил 10%".

Comment: Да, есть правило и у Розенталя: "Вводные слова и словосочетания выделяются запятыми. Различается несколько основных групп вводных слов по их значению:...5) вводные слова (сочетания), указывающие на источник сообщения (говорят, сообщают, передают, по словам…, **по сведениям…**"

Comment: Какие правила?  Практически любое вводное слово может быть как этим вводным словом, так и обстоятельством. Не стоит их различать только по тематике. Я же привела пример замены обстоятельственным оборотом "согласно официальным сообщениям". А эта падежная форма с производным предлогом обособляется факультативно. Этого правила достаточно? Так что всё строго по Розенталю. Даже по интонации варианты явно различимы, так зачем отрицать очевидное.

Comment: Правила я привел из Розенталя (выше в комментарии) и из Лопатина (в своем ответе). Они солидарны и однозначны: вводные слова "по сообщениям...", если указывают на источник информации, **обособляются**.
Да, те же слова могут не быть вводным сочетанием. Но только тогда, когда они не имеют значения указания на источник информации: "По официальным сообщениям нельзя судить о настроениях народа".

Comment: Понял вашу мысль. Очень плохая позиция для обстоятельства. Вряд ли кто-то так сформулирует. В конце лучше. Такой вариант нормален, если есть противопоставление: *Затор составил около 40 км по официальным сообщениям, а не по моему личному мнению.* Другой контекст сложно придумать.

Comment: @bypasser3 Вы уверены, что у ЭТИХ вводных слов есть такая ПРИВИЛЕГИЯ. - никогда не быть обстоятельством? Вот пример: По официальным сообщениям таджикский язык стал послЕдним в СНГ, на котором официально выйдет сайт «Одноклассники». Обычно этот оборот обособляется в распространенных предложениях, так как просто не вписывается в его структуру (например, дальше следует еще одно обстоятельство). Но чем короче предложение, тем меньше шансов быть обязательно обособленным.. В других случаях возможны оба варианта.

Comment: @ oleedd По официАльным сообщениям сайт закрыли, но у меня есть свЕдения, что нЕт.  Надо обособлять?

Comment: Разницу улавливаю, но почему эти исключения не даны в правилах? Хотя бы на Грамоте, где каждое вводное отдельно. А так лучше? *Сайт по официАльным сообщениям закрыли, но у меня есть свЕдения, что нЕт.*

Comment: @ oleedd Когда вы перестанете выкручиваться и дадите мне ясный, короткий и ЧЕСТНЫЙ  ответ: да или нет?  Вопрос был тоже короткий: надо ли обособлять оборот в приведенном предложении, будете ли вы "нарушать" правила? Я понимаю, что отвечать не хочется. Способы уйти об ответа известные: 1) А почему в правилах нет? 2) А может так будет лучше? И т.д.

Comment: Если главный смысл предложения в этом обороте (есть центральное ударение), то его нельзя изъять и он не обособляется, так как не будет вводным. Ваш пример подходит. Но в вашем ответе другое сказано: что ударение при вводном. А оно при вводном малозаметное, а в (1) - сильное.

Comment: Меня интересует только короткий ответ. Вот предложение.Сайт по официАльным сообщениям закрыли, но у меня есть свЕдения, что нЕт.  Нужно обособлять оборот? Да или нет.

Comment: Нет. Сказал же, что ваш пример подходит, чтобы не обособлять. Изъять его нельзя, так как имеется сопоставление: по официальным сообщениям - одно, а у меня сведения другие.

Comment: Итак, ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ НЕ НАДО. Спасибо за ваше мнение.  Значит, правило имеет исключения, что и требовалось доказать  И это благородный поступок, вы мне нравитесь таким.

Comment: Дело в том, что я за истину. А "ломать систему" - не страшно (никто не накажет), а даже прикольно. Но лайки за это обычно не ставят - вокруг скептики, пропитанные формализмом. Разницу в прочтении я вижу, но всё равно сомнение в том, что так можно, остаётся. При необособлении появляется двусмысленность: *сайт по официальным сообщениям [на котором выдаются официальные сообщения]*.