# Объясните, пожалуйста, отсутствие запятой!

Tags: запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова, обстоятельство

***По результатам проверки() у вас нет ошибок в выполненных заданиях***

Я не очень разобрался, почему в этом предложении нет запятой? Разве нельзя *по результатам проверки* считать за вводную конструкцию, указывающую на источник? Мне сложно понять, почему этот оборот является обстоятельством, ведь к нему нельзя задать обстоятельственный вопрос. Проясните мне, пожалуйста, эту ситуацию!

Comment: Я голосую за этот вопрос и хочу сказать, что не всё здесь просто. Его нельзя решать по одной семантике, хотя мы всегда стремимся выразить определенный смысл. Но чтобы сделать это, надо подобрать структуру предложения, которая позволит выразить этот смысл. В конкретном предложении структура уже задана автором, и тогда мы должны ориентироваться на нее тоже.  Иногда возможны варианты, иногда надо учитывать контекст. Формальное решение этой задачи не всегда правильно, и это мнение самого Розенталя, а не лично моё. Я дам ссылку на похожий вопрос, который тоже не выглядел однозначным и вызвал споры.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458218/По-официальным-сообщениям-затор-составил-около-40-км/458220#458220

Comment: @Sharon , а вы могли бы добавить свой ответ? Я изучил материал по вашей ссылке и, к сожалению, никакой конкретики там не нашел. Это действительно затруднительная тема в пунктуации или я что-то недопонял?

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ на комментарий**

1. Игорь, у вас поразительная способность обозначать нечто такое, что имеет очень **обобщенный смысл.** Вы просто философ! Вот вы говорите, что не нашли **конкретики.** А ее там и нет, да и вся конкретика в правилах пунктуации – это только видимость. Чтобы не забывать об этом, регулярно читайте вступление Розенталя к Правилам:

"Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это **исключает формальный подход** к соблюдению правил".

Далее вы  спрашиваете о затруднительных темах. Увы, да, эта тема  **затруднительная.** Более того, я бы всю пунктуацию назвала бы одной очень затруднительной темой.

2. Приведу вам пример для наглядности. Вот Розенталь перечисляет вводные слова, указывающие **на источник сообщения**, В частности, там есть сочетание ***«по сообщению кого-либо»***. Пользователи понимают это правило дословно  и считают, что это всегда так.  (В дискуссии по ссылке как раз об этом речь, там я пытаюсь доказать: нет, не всегда так.)

Далее Розенталь (тоже однозначно) дает список сочетаний, которые вводными не являются. Он приводит пример:  «***По здешним порядкам** так делать не полагалось*».  Но это выражение можно использовать так, что оно будет обособляться просто **при плохой сочетаемости** с последующим текстом, например: ***По здешнему обычаю**, объедать все мясо с кости не следует.* [В. Шинкаренко , 1992].

3. Наши классики уже очень давно говорят о **единстве трех принципов пунктуации**, но мы до сих пор пытаемся решать задачи  в одномерном пространстве – по грамматике, по семантике, по конкретным указаниям в правилах.

Вот и ваш пример нужно решать  путем анализа **вариантов**: (1) сочетание является вводным словом и обособляется;  (2) сочетание является обстоятельством и не обособляется.  В данном случае вводное слово – это всего лишь  обособленное обстоятельство, не более того.

Вам нужен в**ид обстоятельства и вопрос**?  Пусть  это будет обстоятельство  со значением соответствия,  которое отвечает на вопрос  «согласно чему?».

4. Семантический вариант ответа вам предложили, но это всего лишь вариант, возможны и **другие толкования**. Поэтому мне  хотелось бы услышать разные мнения, удивительно, что все молчат. Свой ответ  я дам вам чуть позже.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь всё просто. Если Вы посмотрите соответствующий пункт у Розенталя ([п.5 здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122)), то обнаружите там два перечня, которые можно отнести к источникам информации: сначала перечислены вводные слова (сочетания), затем — не вводные. Правда, оба перечня заканчиваются неопределённым "и др.", но можно уловить простое правило, как их отличать.

Если вы хотите снять с себя ответственность за саму информацию, тогда ссылка на источник будет вводным словом / выражением. В этом случае информация носит субъективный характер и может быть подвержена сомнению хотя бы в принципе.

Если же вы хотите, наоборот, подчеркнуть объективный характер информации, тогда слово (сочетание) не будет вводным, а будет, скорее, служить объяснением последующего высказывания.

В некоторых случаях одно и то же высказывание может пониматься и так и этак, тогда автор ставит или не ставит запятую в зависимости от известного ему контекста.

В приведенном в вопросе предложении имеется в виду, вероятно, что "результат проверки" является неким объективным критерием и объясняет, почему сделан вывод о том, что "нет ошибок в выполненных заданиях".

Comment: Спасибо! То есть это обстоятельство? Тогда какого оно вида и какой обстоятельственный вопрос можно задать?

Comment: @ИгорьБолотов Я не считаю данное предложение стилистически корректным, но всё же обстоятельство "по результатам проверки" отношу к обстоятельствам причины (как и весь второй перечень Розенталя). Можно задать вопрос *на каком основании?*

Answer (score 1):

1. Итак, мы уже пришли к пониманию того, что данная падежная форма может быть необособленным обстоятельством или обособленным вводным словом.

(1) ***По результатам проверки** у вас нет ошибок в выполненных заданиях.*

(2) ***По результатам проверки**, у вас нет ошибок в выполненных заданиях.*

2. Интонационно возможны оба варианта, поэтому решение ориентировано на **семантику и стиль**.

**Первый вариант** более предпочтителен. Такое заключение может дать комиссия, проверяющая работу, это обычный **официальный** стиль для оформления подобных документов, итог проведенной проверки.

**Второй же вариант** записи выглядит странно, как будто отсутствие ошибок в принципе не исключается и может быть выявлено иным способом.

**Примечание.**  Обычно в таких случаях указывается проверяющая организация, например: по результатам проверки школьной комиссией или региональной комиссией. Тогда при отсутствии запятой  сообщается о результатах проверки,  а при  обособлении оборота дается **привязка** сделанного вывода к конкретной организации. Это имеет определенный смысл,  если работа будет проверяться **на разных уровнях.**

3. **Однозначное решение** возможно в сложном предложении при сопоставлении, например:

*По результатам проверки **шкОльной** комиссии у вас нет ошибок в выполненных заданиях, но при **городскОй** проверке такие ошибки были выявлены.*

Здесь постановка логических ударений исключает обособление.

Comment: Благодарю! Но в предыдущем вашем ответе вы назвали такой оборот «обстоятельством соответствия». Разве такие бывают? (Или я чего-то не понял?)

Comment: Бывают, бывают, даже синие зайцы бывают. Помните, у Толстого: Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой: «Бывают ли синие зайцы?», не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают». (Но это шутка.) Обстоятельства тоже бывают разные, просто одни имеют устоявшиеся названия, а  другие нет. К примеру, придаточные обстоятельственные предложения называются так же, как обстоятельства: цели, причины  и т.д. Но там есть и другие придаточные –   сравнительные, сопоставительные и др. Также существуют различные обстоятельственные обороты с производными предлогами, в том числе со значением соответствия.

Comment: Спасибо, помню) А вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, скинуть ссылку на материал, где упоминались бы обстоятельства соответствия? Я пока не могу найти.

Comment: Я полагаю, что они нигде не упоминаются, да и вам я не советую упоминать. Такие обстоятельства называют с просто обстоятельствами, они - безымянные. Но вы ведь согласны с тем, что мы должны как-то назвать второстепенный член, который не является ни  дополнением, ни определением. Существует понятие функция обстоятельства, есть общее определение обстоятельства: по отношению к действию обстоятельство обозначает различные качественные и количественные признаки этого действия.  Вот фраза из Розенталя: падежная форма выполняет функцию обстоятельства и не обособляется.