# Правильно ли написано предложение? Нужны ли тут запятые?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я послал бы всех матом и пошёл бы нажрался.

Answer (score 2):

Коммуникативность фразы не очень ясна. Если это выражение внутреннего желания (а не ответ на вопрос), то лучше сказать так (с инверсией подлежащего):

***Послал бы я** всех матом и **пошёл бы нажрался**.*

Запятые не нужны. Все глаголы употреблены в форме **сослагательного наклонения,** при этом два глагола в одинаковой грамматической форме (***пошёл бы нажрался***) используются для обозначения **действия и его цели:**

Сравнить: ***Пойду погуляю** в саду.*

Простое глагольное сказуемое, способы его выражения, пункт 1(5) http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#31201

Comment: Это к вам, вы шарите: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471800 Хотелось бы хоть чуть-чуть правил.

Comment: Да, oleedd, я его видела и знаю ответ, но сейчас у меня нет настроения отвечать.  Может, позже.

Comment: А правила? Хоть капельку... Мне хочется поставить только одно тире.

Comment: Тире здесь интонационный знак.  И задача решается методом интонационного анализа. Мы решаем: это вводное сочетание или наречное выражение.  Надо сравнивать варианты. Но я бы обошлась без тире.

Comment: Что-то мне начинает казаться, что "по моему мнению" тоже надо без запятых. Вы мне здесь это объясняли: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458218

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно, запятые не нужны.

Вот только то, как у вас сказано, разговорный вариант. А строго должно быть:

- пошёл бы что-то сдела**ть**
- пошёл бы **и** сделал что-то