# По мнению - всегда ли нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Всегда ли "по мнению" безоговорочно является вводным оборотом? Или все же бывают исключения? И тогда является ли таковым пример ниже?

*По моему мнению, дождя сегодня не будет. Однако по мнению графа дождь будет обязательно.*

В первом предложении, безусловно, "по моему мнению" является вводным и запятой выделяется. Но вопрос в том, нужно ли выделять запятыми (или отделить одной запятой) оборот «по мнению графа» во втором предложении?

Мне кажется, второе "по мнению" не является вводным, а выступает частью речи, на него падает интонационное ударение, и при его пропуске предложение частично теряет свой смысл.

Спрашиваю, поскольку в справочниках удалось найти правило только с однозначной постановкой запятых.

Спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138116/discussion-on-question-by-alenka------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

***По моемУ мнению,** // дождя сегодня не будет. Однако **по мнению графа** / дождь будет обязательно.*

**Пояснение**

***«По моему мнению»*** может быть обособленным вводным сочетанием или необособленным наречным сочетанием в роли обстоятельства. Семантика в этом случае практически **не меняется**, а постановка запятой зависит **от логических ударений.**

**(1) По моемУ мнению, // дождя сегодня не будет.**

Это вводное сочетание, которое обычно обособляется (это более частотный вариант). Причем структура данного предложения **удобна для обособления**: предложение делится паузой на две фразы, **логическим ударением** выделено слово "***по моемУ***" в первой части.

***(2) Однако по мнению графа / дождь будет обязАтельно.***

Это предложение удобно оформить **как простое**, выделять паузами и запятыми ***«по мнению графа»*** неудобно и не имеет смысла. Два предложения **семантически связаны**, и здесь **достаточно логического выделения** «по моему мнению»,  так второе предложение начинается **с противительного союза.** Из этого следует, что мнения разные.

**В основном тексте** примерно та же ситуация. Логически выделена только **первая точка зрения**, а вторая представлена другой формулировкой, отличной от первой.

***По мнению нИзших философских школ**,// совокупности являются наблюдаемым объектом воззрения личной самости. **При этом по мнению прасангиков** / совокупности – это основа для обозначения «я», а наблюдаемым объектом воззрения личной самости будет «лишь я».*

**Примечание**.

(1) Одной косой чертой обозначены короткие **произносительные** паузы.

(2) Обособление – это всегда логическое выделение. В данном случае логическое подчеркивание второй точки зрения является **лишним**, но в тоже время  не запрещается. Тем не менее "лишние" запятые нежелательны в научных текстах, затемняют его содержание, если это лишь формальность, которую требует корректор.

(3) С **интонационным анализом** знакомы не многие. Поэтому использовать его принципы надо в том случае, если вы можете рассчитывать на **понимающую аудиторию.** В противном случае обособляйте все, что похоже на вводную конструкцию (по мнению кого-то), и никаких проблем и лишних вопросов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138115/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Answer (score 1):

В обоих ваших примерах ‟по моему мнению” является вводным сочетанием и будет обособляться. ‟По моему мнению” не вводное сочетание в таком предложении: ‟Дождь будет по мнению графа, а не по моему мнению”. То есть когда это сочетание не является отступлением, предворяющим сообщение этого мнения, а является центром высказывания.

Comment: Здесь как раз является центром высказывания, его нельзя изъять, а то ломается противопоставление. Оно есть и в вашем примере — более явное. То есть ситуация та же.

Comment: Чтобы было что обсуждать можно придумать контекст для этого предложения. Например: ‟Мы ожидали солнечную погоду, однако, по мнению графа, дождь будет обязательность”. Нет, здесь определённо ‟однако” относится к основной части предложения, а не к отступлению об источнике сообщения - ‟по мнению графа”.

Comment: Здесь да, здесь нет двух "*по ... мнению*". Ожидание не мнение.

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Что неясно?....

Comment: Вообще ничего не ясно.

Comment: У меня два коротких предложения, не огромный текст. Соглашаюсь с наличием запятых и говорю, что в вашем примере нет двух мнений.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два "*по ... мнению*" имеют сюжетный смысл, ни то ни другое нельзя изъять, потому что ломается противопоставление, а в нём весь смысл.

В справочниках это упущено. Возможно, лучшим решением здесь будет показать параллелизм (о котором часто говорится у Розенталя) с помощью тире:
*По моему мнЕнию — дождя сегодня не будет. Однако по мнению грАфа — дождь будет обязательно.* || Ударение падает на эти обороты, ещё одна причина для тире.